# How to get/specify info about a programmaticaly-added button in WPF? Or similarly, how to pass custom EventArgs to such a button click event?

Tags: c#, wpf, wpf-controls

Say I added a series buttons to a WPF app progammatically, as part of a label, textbox, button section, and attached a single handler to the click event of all of these. How can I specify which button (pertaining to which section) is being clicked, so it can be handled accordingly?

Attaching individuals handlers won't work since the user must be able to add as many of these 'lines' as needed.

A possible alternative would be to pass information to the event handler, such as:

```cs
    ...
    var sender = this;
    var args = new CustomEventArgs(sectionName);

    var button = new Button();
    button.Click += Button_EventHandler_Click(sender, args);
```

But I haven't found a way to this in C#.

Any help/idea will be appreciated!

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look at the `sender` parameter, it will be the clicked button.

If you need to further differenciate the buttons, you can set the `Tag` property of the `button`.

Comment: Great! Thanks! The `Tag` property does the job. However, one more question: is it possible to attached any object type (string, int, custom) to it?

Comment: @rae1n: `Tag` is of type `object`, you can pass in anything, to get it out again you need to [cast](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173105.aspx) it