# How to pass specific arguments to a programmatically-added button in a WPF app?

Tags: c#, wpf, wpf-controls

Is it possible (and if so, how can it be achieved?) to pass custom args or sender to a programmatically-defined button in WPF? Say I define a button in the code-behind and I want to specify a custom event args to the Click event of the button, or define a different sender (say, the container for this button), can it be done programmatically?

I would like to achieve something like this:

```cs
    ...
    var sender = this;
    var args = new CustomEventArgs(sectionName);

    var button = new Button();
    button.Click += Button_EventHandler_Click(sender, args);
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: [deja-vu](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9571974/how-to-get-specify-info-about-a-programmaticaly-added-button-in-wpf-or-similarl)?

Comment: I realized the previous question did not exactly referred to the above problem, and although the answer was good, I still would like to know if there is a way to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as i know you cannot do that as the `Button` is in charge of creating the event args. You might want to use [commands](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752308.aspx) which allow you to pass a [`CommandParameter`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.primitives.buttonbase.commandparameter.aspx) which then is available in the `Execute` method (which is the counterpart of the click handler).